# BEMcheckbox check/uncheck issue in tableview in swift 3

Tags: ios

I am using BEMcheckbox. when  i click it, it animates and show a hidden label but when I scroll my  tableview  my checkbox is automatically deselected. also when I scroll it doesn't select any checkbox automatically. what I want is when I scroll my tableview the checkbox which are checked remains checked and which are unchecked remains unchecked. my code is below. my view controller class.

```
class markAttendanceViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate{

@IBAction func selectall(_ sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    if sender.isSelected {
        checkImageView.isHidden = false
        checkboxLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    } else{
        checkImageView.isHidden = true
        checkboxLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    }

    table.reloadData()
}

@IBOutlet weak var checkImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var checkboxLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func backToAttendanceView(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var controller: UIViewController!
    controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "listViewController") as! listViewController
    (controller as! listViewController).receivedString = "Mark Attendance"
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    let revealController = self.revealViewController() as! RevealViewController
    revealController.rightViewController = navController
    revealController.rightViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(revealController.panGestureRecognizer())
    self.present(revealController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}



@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

 //var items:Array = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    checkboxLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1
    checkboxLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

   // items = ["Dashboard","Mark Attendance","Update Attendance","delete Attendance","Time Table","Academic Calendar","Reports","About Us","Logout","rbivwe","whefo","ewsow","webkgwo","wbiebfkwbei","ejwvabei","vdkgdvkJDB"]

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "attendanceTableViewCell") as! attendanceTableViewCell
   // cell.studentname?.text = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.serialnumber?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"

    if button.isSelected {
        cell.present.isHidden = false
        cell.box.setOn(true, animated: true)
    }    else
    {
        cell.box.setOn(false, animated: false)
        cell.present.isHidden = true
    }

return cell

}
}
```

My tableview cell class.

```
class attendanceTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,BEMCheckBoxDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var present: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var box: BEMCheckBox!
@IBOutlet weak var studentname: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var serialnumber: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    box.delegate = self


}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
func didTap(_ checkBox: BEMCheckBox) {
    if box.on {

        present.isHidden = false
    } else {

        present.isHidden = true
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is because you are not reusing the cells properly. You have an array to hold the indexes of the selected checkboxes but you are adding or removing them in your code.

Comment: @Adeel  can you please suggest some code updates.  
I am new to swift.   
it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still need a solution for this. The only way I got it work is to add checkBox state each time you tap on it and then check the state in `cellForRowAt` function. My suggestion:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, BEMCheckBoxDelegate {

//...
var checkboxesState: [Int: Bool] = [:]
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = mainTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productCell", for: indexPath) as! ProductCell
    cell.checkBox.delegate = self
    cell.checkBox.tag = indexPath.row
    if let isOn = checkboxesState[indexPath.row] {
        if isOn {
            cell.checkBox.on = true
        } else {
            cell.checkBox.on = false
        }
    } else {
        cell.checkBox.on = false
    }
    //... other code
    return cell
 }
func didTap(_ checkBox: BEMCheckBox) {
    checkboxesState.updateValue(checkBox.on, forKey: checkBox.tag)
}
//...
}
```